# Use OpenSSL in Automator Application?

Tags: applications, automator, encryption, openssl

I want to make an application that's in the same directory as a file: message.txt.enc
If you open the app you should be prompted with a password dialogue. this should be used to decrypt the file AND delete the .enc file

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -in message.txt.enc -out message.txt -pass stdin
```

doesn't do the job

Please help, Thank you!

Comment: Please give more details: What does your automator program look like, which part of it troubles you, etc

Comment: Let me know if this isn't a duplicate of the question that already has a nice answer on how to encrypt and decrypt...